# Passing a valid attribute to controller but failing validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Model:

```
module V1
  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :default_pull_rate, numericality: true, allow_nil: false

    has_many :player_links

  end

end
```

Spec (I even tried explicitly setting the default_pull_rate inline as seen below):

```
 it "creates a new player" do

   expect { post :create, format: :json, player: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:player, default_pull_rate: 5) }.to change(V1::Player, :count).by(1)
 end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :player, class: V1::Player do
    name "Frank"
    default_pull_rate 100
  end
```

Controller:

```
....
def create
  @player = Player.new(player_params)

  if @player.save!
    redirect_to @player
  end
end

private

def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :default_pull_rated)
end
```

Error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Default pull rate is not a number
```

Passing model specs:

```
it "is invalid without a default_pull_rate" do
   expect(FactoryGirl.build(:player, default_pull_rate: nil)).to_not be_valid
 end

 it "is invalid when default_pull_rate is a string" do
   expect(FactoryGirl.build(:player, default_pull_rate: "fast")).to_not be_valid
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in `player_params`?

```
def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :default_pull_rated)
end
```

should be `_rate` not `_rated`

```
def player_params
  params.require(:player).permit(:name, :default_pull_rate)
end
```